# Changing the word "one" to the number "1" and so on

Tags: java

I am NOT asking you guys to do my work for before you get the idea, its just i was handed this assignment

> Complete the function int comp(String s1, String s2). For this
>   function, s1 and s2 are one of the following 
>   "one","two","three","four". For example, s1 might be two and s2 might
>   be four. Clearly s1 and s2 correspond to numbers.  The function comp
>   should return a negative number if s1 (as a number) is less than s2
>   (as a number), zero if they are equal (as numbers), and a positive
>   number otherwise.  For example, comp("two","four") should return a
>   negative number because 2 is less than 4.

BUT I have no idea how I would assign s1 with 1 if it's already been assigned "one".

Any tips?

Best Regards.

Comment: A `Map<String,Integer>` would suit you very nicely.

Comment: Basically you need to map Strings to Integers, do you know any data structures for that?

Comment: Create a natural language parser for numbers, what if I want to call `comp("Onehundredfiftytwo", "Sixtyseven")`?

Comment: @cmmi wouldnt it be a hasmap i'd need to use?

Comment: @user3259071 a Hashmap could do it, yes.

Comment: @user3259071 do you see `enum` implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possiblitys two put the string and the number together(enums, objects, mapping), but the best way is to solve it is a mapping of `String`, `Integer`.

```
public class test
{
    private HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public test(){
        map.put("one",1);
        map.put("two",2);
        map.put("three",3);
        map.put("four",4);
        //TODO: ....
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.print(new test().comp("two","four"));

    }

    public int comp(String s1, String s2) {
        int i1 = map.get(s1);
        int i2 = map.get(s2);
        return (i1<i2 ? -1 : (i1==i2 ? 0 : 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if inputs is limited to `"one","two","three","four"` you can use `String.equals` and `if-else` blocks to assign correct int value. something like this:

```
private int parseInt(String s) {
    if(s.equals("one"))
        return 1;
    if(s.equals("two"))
        return 2;
...
}
```

**UPDATE**
one interesting implementation can be done by `enum`:

```
public class Main {

    public enum NUMBER {

        zero("zero", 0), one("one", 1), two("two", 2), three("three", 3), four("four", 4);

        private String  string;
        private int     number;

        NUMBER(String s, int n) {
            string = s;
            number = n;
        }

        public int getInt() {
            return number;
        }
    };

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(compare("one", "two"));
        System.out.println(compare("one", "one"));
        System.out.println(compare("zero", "two"));
        System.out.println(compare("four", "two"));
    }

    public static int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int n1 = NUMBER.valueOf(s1).getInt();
        int n2 = NUMBER.valueOf(s2).getInt();
        return Integer.compare(n1, n2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use a comparative array:

```
String[] value = {"one", "two", "three", "four"}

public int comp(String s1, String s2) {
    int one = getVal(s1);
    int two = getVal(s2);
    // Compare how you like
    return Integer.compare(one, two);
}

public int getVal(String rel) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        // i - 1 due to array indexes starting at 0.
        if (value[i - 1].equalsIgnoreCase(rel)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return /* some error value for inability to parse */;
}
```

I particularly like this because you don't need to use `Integer.parseInt()` which can throw a runtime exception if the number isn't readable. You could however throw one yourself if the `getVal` function doesn't find an appropriate number.

Future proofing if you wanted to use any number, I would say that it could be plausible by breaking the numbers down by digits and concatenating them as numerical digits instead, but that might be a little more advanced than the current objective here :)

Comment: because he's a beginner. he didn't even understand how "one" could equal 1, (not trying to be mean OP) Although the solution does work, using a double ternary expression for a return value on an assignment of this nature is simply going to confuse.

Comment: I left a comment in my code that he could compare however he likes, my answer isn't there to be copy/pasted but to help display how something could be done. Using a loop for this isn't a complicated concept and it's a good one to take up.

Comment: @WillBD answers on SO are meant for everybody, not just for the poster. If it's right, it's right. Don't downvote for the reason that you mentioned. And in any case, Rogue didn't post rocket science here.

Comment: I'll change the downvote

Comment: Ack, thanks for the catch @MarkoTopolnik, thought I missed something taking `zero` out of the array :)

Comment: BTW for comparison you can use a built-in: `return Integer.compare(one, two);` and slash the downvote-attracting double ternary.